# Show that $\big(s(. |C_n)\big)_n$ is equicontinuous on $X^*$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a separable Banach space with dual $X^*$. $\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$ be the class of nonempty, weakly-compact and convex subsets of $X$. For any $C\in\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$  we define its support function $s(.|C):X^*\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by:
$$
s(x^*|C):=\sup_{x\in C} \langle x^*,x \rangle\qquad \forall x^*\in X^*
$$
and its radius by :

$$
\|C\|:=\sup_{x\in C}\|x\|
$$

Let $(C_n)_n\subset \mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$ such that :
$$
\exists M>0~,~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}~,~\|C_n\|\leq M
$$
Show that  $\big(s(. |C_n)\big)_n$ is equicontinuous on $X^*$.

An idea to make this proof please.

Comment: What is the range of the mapping $x^*\mapsto (s(.|C_n))_n$?

Comment: I do not know sir. can you help me please

Comment: If one doesn't know the question, how can one give an answer? Could it be that you are actually talking about the map $x^*\mapsto s(x^*|C)$?

Comment: Ahh, but i have already defined  $s (.|C)$, sir. it is: $$x^*\to s (x^*|C)=\sup_{x\in C} \langle x^*,x \rangle $$

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question; please ignore my remarks!

Comment: Isn't $s(.|C)$ Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $\|C\|$ and hence your family uniformly Lipschitz continuous with constant $M$?